# Why can’t I edit HTML in WordPress even with the administrator role?

Tags: html

I am using WordPress. I need to edit the HTML code of the page. Not `page.php`.

When I go to `http://example.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=448&action=edit`, I see this:

[image: Screenshot]

And after some time shows this message:

> “You are not able to…”

My role is administrator. If there are other ways to edit the HTML or to correct the error please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the WP Element plugin to control your content, as such HTML editing is disabled because the HTML source is basically impossible to edit by hand, as it contains all the format, content, blocks ( json ) and other configuration options which are stored together in the post_content.

Perhaps you can create new pages and not assign them to be edited with Element, this would then allow you access to edit the HTML.